# Godot 4.0 Platformer Movement Not Working

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm new to coding and the game developing scene, so for my first project, I'm trying to make a Mario esc platformer in Godot. Using multiple YouTube tutorials as well as ChatGPT, I came up with code for the movement. However, I've run into an issue where whenever I don't stop moving. This occurred after asking GPT to help me add friction. This is what the code looks like now:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed: float = 200.0

# Jumping physics
@export var jump_height: float
@export var jump_time_to_peak: float
@export var jump_time_to_descend: float

var jump_velocity: float
var jump_gravity: float
var fall_gravity: float

var previous_direction: int = 0

var friction: float = 0.01

var gravity: float = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

func _ready():
    jump_velocity = ((2.0 * jump_height) / jump_time_to_peak) * -1.0
    jump_gravity = ((-2.0 * jump_height) / jump_time_to_peak * jump_time_to_peak) * -1.0
    fall_gravity = ((-2.0 * jump_height) / jump_time_to_descend * jump_time_to_descend) * -1.0

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    velocity.y += _get_gravity() * delta
    
    var direction: float = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    
    if direction != 0.0:
        if direction > 0.0:
            previous_direction = 1
        else:
            previous_direction = -1
        velocity.x = previous_direction * speed
    else:
        if is_on_floor():
            velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, friction * delta)
        else:
            if velocity.x != 0.0:
                var sign: float
                if velocity.x > 0.0:
                    sign = 1.0
                else:
                    sign = -1.0
                velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, friction * delta) + sign * speed * delta
    
    velocity.x = previous_direction * speed
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        _jump()
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        _jump()

    move_and_slide()

func _get_gravity() -> float:
    return jump_gravity if velocity.y < 0.0 else fall_gravity

func _jump() -> void:
    velocity.y = jump_velocity
```

I've tried if else blocks, syntax errors, and asking ChatGPT to help multiple times. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are the issues I notice on the code:

- You are comparing `float`s with `0.0`, which sometimes it is fine, but in general we cannot rely on a `float` that is steadily incremented or decremented each frame to hit exactly `0.0` due to possible rounding issues. So, instead we use the method `is_zero_approx`. You might also be interested in `is_equal_approx`.
- Your friction seems to be too small. The method `move_toward` takes as third parameter the maximum amount it can change, and you are passing `friction * delta`, where `delta` is a time in seconds from the last frame (so it is usually a value less than `1.0` or you have bigger problems) and `friction` is set to `0.01`... And since you are working in 2D, your distance units are pixels. So we are talking of a maximum change rate of a fraction of a pixel per second, which won't be noticeable.
- I fail to understand the logic for the movement in the air which both applies a friction that reduces the speed, but you are also adding a speed in the same direction.
- And the friction won't do anything anyway, because you overwrite the changes to `velocity.x` with `velocity.x = previous_direction * speed` after the conditional (so this happens regardless of input). Since that is the problem you are asking about (it does not stop moving) **start by removing this line**.
- The conditional where you call `_jump` is needlessly duplicated.

In fact, I believe you don't need to keep `previous_direction` at all, instead you could use `signf(direction)` - or better yet: use `direction` directly, which would give you support for analog input (which is the point of using `get_action_strength` instead of `is_action_pressed`).

*The variable `previous_direction` might be useful in the future depending on what do you plan to implement, but removing it might simplify your code, and you might reintroduce it later if you need it.*

Comment: thanks a lot, i have very little experience with coding and this helped a ton.